# emacs persistant buffer list

Tags: emacs, buffer

In vim, I can have a nice small window that lists all my open buffers by using minibufexplorer.  I can navigate to it and switch buffers.

Is there a persistant buffer list plugin for emacs?

I'm looking for something similar to this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCtHT.png

At the bottom of the screenshot, you can see a list of the different buffers he has open.

Any ideas?

Comment: You may want to check out the [possible methods of buffer switching in Emacs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryBufferSwitching). There are quite a few alternatives developed by users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use `buffer-menu`.  I bind it to <kbd>C-x C-b</kbd> (instead of `list-buffers`).  It is the same thing as `list-buffers`, but it also lets you *act* on buffers.
2. Have a look at [**Buffer Menu+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BufferMenuPlus), which enhances the vanilla buffer menu (`list-buffers`, `buffer-menu`).
3. Make buffer `*Buffer List*` (used by <kbd>C-x C-b</kbd>) use its own frame, which you can leave displayed (or iconified) for easy access.  To do that, make it a *special-display* buffer -- see options `special-display-regexps` and `special-display-buffer-names`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of open buffers with `list-buffers` (<kbd>C-x C-b</kbd>).  To keep a bar showing open buffers visible at all times, take a look at [`tabbar-mode`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TabBarMode).  `tabbar-mode` is packaged in the [marmalade](http://marmalade-repo.org/) repository, so you can install it through the package manager if you've installed `package.el` or if you're using emacs 24 or later.